# edismax with multiple words for keyword tokenizer splitting on space

Tags: solr, lucene, solrcloud, solr4j

There are two fields in my schema:

***`field1`*** is using `keyword` tokenizer filter that preserves the tokens as it is (not even dividing on space. I double checked that in analysis tab.)

***`field2`*** is using `WhitespaceTokenizerFactory` that breaks the words on spaces and tabs etc.

> `<field name="field1"  type="field1_type" indexed="true" stored="false"/>`
>   
> `<field name="field2"  type="field2_type" indexed="true" stored="false"/>`
>   
> `<fieldType name="field2_type" class="solr.TextField">
>       <analyzer type="index">
>           <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
>           <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
>       </analyzer>
>       <analyzer type="query">
>           <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
>           <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
>           <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt"/>
>       </analyzer>
>   </fieldType>`

I am using `edismax` parser with default `qf` value= `field1` `field2`

Now when I'm querying with `q=hello world`

In deugging mode its showing that its making query like

> ***rawquerystring***:hello world
>
> ***querystring***:hello world 
>   ***parsedquery***:(+((DisjunctionMaxQuery((field1:hello | field2:hello)) DisjunctionMaxQuery((field1:world | field2:world)))~1)
>   ())/no_coord
>
> **parsedquery_toString**:+(((field1:hello | field2:hello) (field1:world | field2:world))~1) ()

What I expected was something like this:

> ***expected***:+(((field1:hello world) ((field2:hello)  (field2:world))~1) ()

i.e. for `field1` it should not break the query on space as it is using keyword tokenizer while it should break the query on space for `field2`.
Can you please tell what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape the space in your query (using backslash or quotes around the term) - the query parser doesn't parse based on the analyzer/tokenizer for each field.